# Global property of one class is not recognised by the class object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

What is wrong with this? Why this global property is not recognised by the class object? Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Synthesize your property in implementation(Viewcontroller2.m) file

Comment: It has nothing to do with synthesizing the property.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention it into the question details.
But I synthesized the property in the of ViewController2.m file but didn't it worked at all.

Comment: What's wrong ?any Idea @Rajatp ?

Comment: @Ayon Chowdhury will you post some more code.

Comment: If I forgot to import the ViewController2.h than I might not be able to create an object of that class. Please think before answer @Jatin

Comment: I have checked your code and it is working.It will be better if you show some more code.

Comment: I just added screenshot of that @Rajatap
I also tested it with another classes. There it's  working well but what wrong with this class?

Comment: Really weird bug.Not able to replicate that.

Comment: Why is that property `weak`?

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me sometimes, and is sometimes corrected by a clean, and always fixed by updating and saving my .pch file.

**Try cleaning your project. (Shft-Ctrl-K)** This could eliminate some old symbol cache that is preventing the new symbols from being read.

**Try saving a new edit to your .pch file or some imported header file**. This could force an update of symbols in Xcode.